# Document not rendered correctly in Acrobat

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays, transparency, acrobat

I'm creating a document with an image I want placed in the background.  But, I want to partially cloud out the background image.  My code works as desired.  The problem is how it is rendered in different pdf viewers.  With `skim` or Mac OSx's `Preview`, the document is rendered correctly.  However, `Acrobat` does not render this correctly.

Here's my code for the background image, which I call `fig/fig_01` in the main document:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw[fill=yellow] (0,0) coordinate (NW) rectangle (-45:2in) coordinate (SE);

  \draw [line width=4pt,blue,rounded corners=1.5pt]
        (NW|-SE) --
        ($(NW|-SE)!1/3!(SE)$) -- 
        ($(NW-|SE)!1/2!(NW)$) --
        ($(NW|-SE)!2/3!(SE)$) --
        (SE);
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the code for the main document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

   \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] 
      at (current page.north west) 
      {\includegraphics[angle=0,width=\paperwidth]{fig/fig_01}};

   \draw[fill=white,opacity=50] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);

  \node[scale=47] 
      at ($(current page.center)+(0pt,3cm)$) 
      {\bfseries\sffamily ?};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Granted my MWE isn't particular beautiful, but that's not the point.

The result should appear as:

[image]

But in Acrobat is is rendered as:

[image]

This is a document that I am creating to share with other people.  I want them to see the image as I've designed it.

I am aware that different software may or may not render pdf images the same way.  But, I thought Acrobat would at least do this correctly.  (Incidentally, in Gmail it's also not rendered correctly either, but I don't understand whether it's actually Gmail, my browswer, or something else in that case.  But I can work around gmail by telling folk, "don't just look at this in your browser.  Download it and view with ...."

What can I do differently so that this document gets rendered correctly with `Skim`, Mac OSx's `Preview`, and `Acrobat`?

Comment: Shouldn't `opacity=50` be `opacity=0.5`? On Linux, I get a white background with `opacity=50` but the correct look with `opacity=0.5` with both poppler and mupdf based PDF software (and pdfjs for Firefox). (Actually, it's still a little darker than your first screenshot unless I go up to 0.7 or 0.8.)

Comment: as @frabjous wrote, your opacity setting if faulty and acrobat is correct here, the other viewers are doing it wrong.

Comment: @frabjous I hadn't even thought of that as the issue.  I don't know where I got the idea that opacity was between 0 and 100.  Issue resolved.  My faith in Acrobat restored.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer My default viewer is Skim.  i hadn't even considered that Acrobat wasn't working until someone told me the file I sent them, which they opened in Acrobat, was nearly empty.  And because Skim and Preview were rendering things as I wanted, I hadn't even considered my choice of opacity outside of [0,1] to be the issue.